# Complex root of $Z^{60}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find $z$ such that $z^{60}=-1$ but $z^{k} \neq -1$ with $k< 60$.

> > Try : $z$ must be of the form $e^{i \frac{(2m+1) \pi}{60}}$ for $0<=m<=59$. So $k$ must satisfy $k(2m+1)=60(2n+1)$.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense.  There are 60 possible values for z.  How many solutions for *k* depend on which value for z you choose.  z = $e^{\frac{\pi i}{60}}$ will have all 60 solutions but $e^{\frac{\pi i}4}$ will only have 45 solutions.  Did you mean solve for $z$?

Comment: @fleablood Yes. I have reframed the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question makes more sense if it asks "Find $z$ such that $z^{60}=-1$ but $z^k\ne-1$ for $k<60$." In that case we have $z^{60}=-1=e^{i\pi}$, so a primitive solution is $z_1=e^{\frac{i\pi}{60}}$. Now if $0<n<120$ is not relatively prime to $60$, that is $\gcd(n,60)=d>1$, then $n=qd$ so $\frac{60}dn=60q$ and we have
$$\left(z_1^n\right)^{\frac{60}d}=z_1^{\frac{60}dqd}=z_1^{60q}=\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{60}}\right)^{60q}=e^{i\pi q}=-1$$
provided $q$ is odd. The only way $q$ could be even is if $n$ were divisible by $8$ but then $$\left(z_1^8\right)^{60}=\left(z_1^{60}\right)^8=(-1)^8=1\ne-1$$
So we must have $\gcd(n,60)=1$ and $\phi(60)=\phi(4)\cdot\phi(3)\cdot\phi(5)=2\cdot2\cdot4=16$, so there are $8$ solutions for $0<n<60$, and since $60+n$ is a solution if $n$ is, there are 16 more solutions for $60<n<120$. The solutions are therefore $z=e^{\frac{n\pi i}{60}}$, $n\in\{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,49,53,59,61,67,71,73,77,79,83,89,91,97,101,103,107,109,113,119\}$

Answer (score 0):

> Solve $z$ in this question:
>
> - $$z^x=s$$

$$z^x=s\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^x=|s|e^{\arg[s]i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\left(|s|e^{\left(2\pi k+\arg[s]\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=|s|^{\frac{1}{x}}e^{\frac{1}{x}\left(2\pi k+\arg[s]\right)i}$$

With $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-(x-1)$