# is this method for solving a complex equation correct?

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find roots of this complex equation:
$$\left(|z|^2 + 3 |z|\right)^2  \left(z^8 - 1\right)^3 = 0$$
(for the moment, let's focus only on the first parenthesis)
$$\left(|z|^2 + 3 |z|\right)^2 = 0$$

My attempt:
I collected $|z|$, because it's a common term.
I got $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = 0$, and the other expression is always false, because norm is always positive.
the first one could be rewritten as $a^2 + b^2 = 0$, and this is the equation of a circle of radius = $0$. so it's a point (i.e the origin).

does this method make sense? is it correct? Or, should I use :
$$\rho = |z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$
instead?

Comment: Please use simple bars instead of double bars for modulus.

Comment: the single bars stand for the absolute value, and during calculus 1 lectures I personally found it a little bit confusing; therefore I've chosen the double bars notation.

Comment: Sum of positive numbers equal zero means that all the numbers in the sum are null.
|z| is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you wrote:

$$\underbrace{\Re\left(\text{z}\right)^2+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)^2}_{:=\space x}+3\sqrt{\underbrace{\Re\left(\text{z}\right)^2+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)^2}_{=\space x}}=0\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$x+3\sqrt{x}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\sqrt{x}\left(3+\sqrt{x}\right)=0 \space\Longrightarrow\space x=0\tag2$$

And solving:

$$\text{z}^8=1\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{z}=\exp\left(\frac{\pi \text{k}}{4}\cdot i\right)\tag3$$

With $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\le\text{k}\le7$.

Comment: could you explain better (3)? I didn't get why did you use the exponential function

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini Take a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730632/complex-root-of-z60/1730676#1730676